# How to use RESTful API with Vuex and Axios for Dashboard

Tags: rest, vue.js, axios, vuex, dashboard

I am new to both Vuex and REST APIs but need to wire a dashboard to a backend REST API using Vuex and Axios and having some trouble.

For example, I need to add a participant to our array of participants, which is one of our states in the Vuex store. I have some actions started here, such as 'Load Participants' which connects to our backend and loads all the participant data. and 'Add participant' which should add a participant.

I am confused on the flow and how to also connect the live info from our dashboard to this. On our dashboard, we have a 'new participant' form that you can enter name, email, sex, etc. on to. How do I have the data submitted from that entered into the my new participant object?

Here is a snippet of the actions:

```
actions: {
async loadParticipants ({commit}) {
  try {
    await axios
      .get('/dash/participants')
      .then(r => r.data)
      .then(participants => {
        commit('setParticipants', participants)
      })
  }

  catch (e) {
    if (e.response)
      commit('Error?')

    throw e
  }
},


async getFilteredParticipants ({ state, commit, getters}) {
  try {
    const {data: participants} = await axios.get('dash/participants')
    commit('filterParticipants', participants, getters)
  }
  catch (e) {
    if (e.response)
      commit('Error?')

    throw e
  }

  }
},

async addParticipant ({ state, commit})
{
  //Need to get this data from New Participant modal?
  const participant = {
    name: 'Amy',
    email: 'amy@gmail.com',
    sex: 'female',
    tags: ['dog', 'cat'],
    createdBy: null,
    updatedBy: null,
    pendingEvalSentDate: Date,
    pendingEvalViewedEmailDate: Date,
    pendingEvalClickedLinkDate: Date,
    completedEvalHistorySummary: null
  }

  try {
    await axios
      .post('/dash/participants')
      commit('addParticipants', participant)
  }
  catch (e) {
    if (e.response)
      commit('Error?')

    throw e
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template:
`<form action="" v-on:submit.prevent="submitParticipant">`

Then, you have to create a submit method in your "New Participant" component, for example:

```
submitParticipant() {
   this.$store.dispatch('addParticipant', this.participant);
}
```

or:

```
submitParticipant() {
   this.$store.dispatch('participantModule/addParticipant', this.participant);
}
```

if your store is divided into modules and `addParticipant` is kept in `participantModule`.

Considering you keep your currently edited participant in your component's data:

```
data() {
   return {
      participant: {} 
   }
}
```

then your `addParticipant` action in store would look like this:

```
addParticipant({ commit }, participant) {
   axios.post('/dash/participants', participant)
        .then(response => {
           console.log(response);
           commit('addParticipants', participant)
         })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```